# How to recover a Perl program from where it exited

Tags: perl

I have a Perl programs that will takes a long time to run. The user may exit it occasionally and I hope to implement a mechanism to recover the program from where it exited.

I have an idea to use `Storable/Dumper` module to save the state of the program before it exited and restore the state after it resumed.

But how can I move the program to where it exited? Can I just set a recover point from where it exited and move to the recover point directly after it resumed?

Comment: Read up on [Finite State Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). And check out [this code](http://search.cpan.org/~koscielny/FSM-Simple-0.02/lib/FSM/Simple.pm). You can refactor your code so that you can use the state machines.

Comment: Would it make sense to suspend the process instead of exiting? you can catch the TSTP and CONT signals. Check this out http://superuser.com/questions/476873/what-is-effect-of-ctrl-z-on-a-unix-linux-application

Comment: [You will encounter some difficulties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionian_School_%28philosophy%29#Heraclitus).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concept of transactions and design the program around that, but having the user kill a process as an expected way of interacting with it doesn't sound like a good idea.
Maybe giving better feedback to the user about the program state would solve this issue instead of dealing with hacky behaviour.